# Слайдер с изображениями вместо точек навигации

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Существует множество готовых плагинов для создания слайдера-карусели на сайте. 
Не хочется изобретать велосипед, но ни разу не встречала реализация, где бы вместо точек навигации были изображения, как на картинке ниже. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос, можно ли настроить плагины типа Slick Slider или OwlCarousel для такого изображения, и если нет, то как самому такое реализовать?

Comment: Конечно, например с помощью css. Может решение не самое лучшие, однако оно покрывает все Ваши жедания. Второй вариан - OwlCarousel имеет API, в каком можно видоизменить)

Comment: Owl Carousel 2 Thumbnails _https://codepen.io/sirnightowl/pen/JoJwrE

Слайдер с миниатюрами на JQuery _http://beloweb.ru/javascript-jquery/primeryi-besplatnyih-jquery-slayderov-dlya-izobrazheniy.html
Owl Carousel 2 Thumbnails plugin _https://github.com/gijsroge/OwlCarousel2-Thumbs

Answer (score 1):

Вот можешь посмотреть мой слайдер https://github.com/VasylBakanovskyi/Slider 
Посмотри как я сделал. Остальное - только дело фантазии

```js
const slider = document.querySelectorAll('.slider');

for (var n = 0; n < slider.length; n++) {
 createIconBlock(slider[n]);

 slider[n].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const el = e.target;
  const parentSlider = el.closest('.slider');
  const icons = parentSlider.querySelectorAll('.icon');
  const slides = parentSlider.querySelectorAll('.slide');
  const activeSlide = parentSlider.querySelector('.active');
  let currentSlide;

  if (el.classList.contains('next')) {
   
   for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    if (slides[i].classList.contains('active')) {
     currentSlide = i;
    }
    slides[i].classList.remove('active');
    icons[i].classList.remove('icon-active');
   }
 
   if (currentSlide >= (slides.length - 1)) {
    currentSlide = 0;
    slides[currentSlide].classList.add('active');
    icons[currentSlide].classList.add('icon-active');
   } else {
    currentSlide++;
    slides[currentSlide].classList.add('active');
    icons[currentSlide].classList.add('icon-active');
   }
  }
  if (el.classList.contains('prev')) {
   
   for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    if (slides[i].classList.contains('active')) {
     currentSlide = i;
    }
    slides[i].classList.remove('active');
    icons[i].classList.remove('icon-active');
   }
 
   if (currentSlide <= 0) {
    currentSlide = slides.length - 1;
    slides[currentSlide].classList.add('active');
    icons[currentSlide].classList.add('icon-active');
   } else {
    currentSlide--;
    slides[currentSlide].classList.add('active');
    icons[currentSlide].classList.add('icon-active');
   }
  }
  if (el.classList.contains('full')) {
   parentSlider.classList.toggle('slider-full');
   parentSlider.querySelector('.slides').classList.toggle('slides-height');
   
   if (parentSlider.querySelector('.slider-full')) {
    icons.forEach( icon => {
     icon.style.width = (document.documentElement.clientWidth / slides.length) + 'px';
     icon.style.height = (document.documentElement.clientHeight / slides.length) + 'px';
    })
   } else {
    icons.forEach( icon => {
     icon.style.width = (parseInt(activeSlide.width) / slides.length) + 'px';
     icon.style.height = (parseInt(activeSlide.height) / slides.length) + 'px';;
    })
   }
  }
  if (el.classList.contains('icon')) {
   const order = el.getAttribute('data-order');

   icons.forEach( item => item.classList.remove('icon-active'));
   el.classList.add('icon-active');
   
   slides.forEach( item => item.classList.remove('active'));
   slides[order].classList.add('active');
  }
 })
}

function createIconBlock(num) {
 const slides = num.querySelectorAll('.slide');

 for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
  const iconImg = document.createElement('img');

  if (i === 0) {
   iconImg.classList.add('icon-active');
  }
  iconImg.classList.add('icon');
  iconImg.setAttribute('data-order', i);

  iconImg.src = slides[i].src;
  iconImg.style.width = (parseInt(slides[0].width) / slides.length) + 'px';
  iconImg.style.height = (parseInt(slides[0].height) / slides.length) + 'px';

  num.querySelector('.icon-block').appendChild(iconImg);
 }
};
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.slider {
 width: 800px;
 margin: 20px auto;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 position: relative;
}
.prev, .next, .full {
 width: 35px;
 height: 35px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 cursor: pointer;
 opacity: 0.4;
 transition: .2s;
}
.prev, .next {
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -35px; 
}
.prev {
 left: 20px;
}
.next {
 right: 20px;
}
.full {
 top: 20px;
 right: 20px;
 background-color: #fff;
}
.prev:hover, .next:hover, .full:hover {
 opacity: 0.8;
}
.slides {
 width: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center
}
.slides-height {
 height: 60vh;
}
.slides img {
 width: 100%;
}
.slide {
 display: none;
}
.active {
 display: block;
}
.icon-block {
 display: flex;
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 20px;
}
.icon {
 cursor: pointer;
}
.icon-active {
 border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(250, 1, 1);
}
.slider-full {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 margin: 0;
}
```

```html
 <div class="slider">
  <img class="full" src="images/full.png" alt="Previous slide">
  <img class="prev" src="images/left.png" alt="Previous slide">
  <img class="next" src="images/right.png" alt="Next slide">
  <div class="slides slides-height">
   <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/VasylBakanovskyi/Slider/master/images/1.jpg" alt="Slide 1" class="slide active">
   <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/VasylBakanovskyi/Slider/master/images/2.jpg" alt="Slide 2" class="slide">
   <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/VasylBakanovskyi/Slider/master/images/3.jpg" alt="Slide 3" class="slide">
   <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/VasylBakanovskyi/Slider/master/images/4.jpg" alt="Slide 4" class="slide">
   <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/VasylBakanovskyi/Slider/master/images/5.jpg" alt="Slide 5" class="slide">
   <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/VasylBakanovskyi/Slider/master/images/6.jpg" alt="Slide 6" class="slide">
   <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/VasylBakanovskyi/Slider/master/images/7.jpg" alt="Slide 7" class="slide">
   <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/VasylBakanovskyi/Slider/master/images/8.jpg" alt="Slide 8" class="slide">
   <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/VasylBakanovskyi/Slider/master/images/9.jpg" alt="Slide 9" class="slide">
   <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/VasylBakanovskyi/Slider/master/images/10.jpg" alt="Slide 10" class="slide">
  </div>
  <div class="icon-block"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Да, такое есть в плагинах каруселей. Суть в том, что на макете в навигации аватарки людей, а в самой карусели цитаты, т.е. разный контент